# What's wrong with this line in PHP?

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

### Code

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT c1 FROM t1 WHERE c2 = " . $_POST['username'] . " AND c3 = " . $_POST['password'] . "");
```

### Problem

I get `ORA-00904` and `ORA-24374`:

> ORA-00904: string: invalid identifier
>   ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch

Replacing `$_POST` in the code with the fixed string that `$_POST` returns stops the error. It must be the `$_POST` or the way that I'm including it in the code.

For example, `$_POST['username']` is `Doe`, using `$_POST['username']` doesn't work but using `Doe` does.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS CODE! [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) What you think would happen if i would put `1; drop table t1;` into password field?

Comment: I bet that [Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:1:0) knows all Oracle numeric error codes by heart but mortals possibly don't. Please don't mutilate error codes when posting to a forum.

Comment: @Uriel_SVK As I said below to one of the, so-called 'answers', you're assuming too much.

Comment: @user2656114 well if you would be using parametrized queries you would have no problems with quotes....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to make quote query vars. looks like you are passing strings to db

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT c1 FROM t1 WHERE c2 = '" . $_POST['username'] . "' AND c3 = '" . $_POST['password'] . "'");
```

Also escape your post data to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Escaping is the stone age mechanism. The OCI extension does not even provide the required function. There's just no reason to write insecure code on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your line of code is that it's an open door for SQL injection; a call to get your server hacked. Right in the [manual page for the `oci_parse()` function](http://php.net/oci_parse) you're already using you have a example on how to pass parameters to queries:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'begin myproc(:p1, :p2); end;');
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p1', $p1);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p2', $p2, 40);

oci_execute($stid);
```

Your code could look like this:

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT c1 FROM t1 WHERE c2 = :username AND c3 = :password");
oci_bind_by_name($stid, 'username', filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
oci_bind_by_name($stid, 'password', filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
oci_execute($stid);
```

... though it's still be a good idea to do error checking on the return values. All three functions above return `FALSE` on error and you have [oci_error()](http://php.net/oci_error) to fetch an array with last error message.